# Scrolling Navigation Bar doesn't change colour over #triangle-left triangle element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a fixed navigation bar that sits on the left hand side of the window and as you scroll down the page, changes colour depending on what div it is hovering over.

This works fine everywhere a part from when it is scrolling over the div #triangle-left located in the .hero div layer at the top.

I want the navigation to begin white and turn black when it is above the white #triangle-left div.

I have created a js fiddle below, and also have included a github repo if anyone prefers that.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/scroll.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

  <header>

    <div class="hero">
      <div class="overlay">
        <nav class="nav white startLogo">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 566.67 283.33"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#add8e6/* #fff */;}</style></defs><title>Down-Arrow</title><polygon class="cls-1" points="566.67 0 566.67 85.33 283.33 170 0 85.33 0 0 283.33 85.33 566.67 0"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="566.67 114 566.67 198.67 283.33 283.33 0 198.67 0 115 283.33 198.67 566.67 114"/></svg>

        <div id="triangle-left" class="row">
          <nav class="nav black altLogo">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="triangle-right" class="row">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content row">
      <nav class="nav black altLogo">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="skewedBox row">
      <nav class="nav white altLogo">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="skewedBox-container">
        <h1>Online Tutorial</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>

  <!-- Main Container -->
  <main>

    <section id="section1" class="row">
      <nav class="nav black altLogo">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>

    <div class="floating-boxes row">
      <div class="overlay">
        <nav class="nav white altLogo">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- First Div -->
        <div id="primary">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Article 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Secondary Div -->
        <div id="secondary">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Article 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Tertiary Div -->
        <div id="tertiary">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Article 3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <section id="section2" class="row">
    <nav class="nav black altLogo">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h2>Our Partners</h2>
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <div>
      <!-- Logo 1 -->
      <img src="../img/company-name.png" alt="company-name-logo"/>
      <!-- Logo 2 -->
      <img src="../img/dove.png" alt="dove-logo"/>
      <!-- Logo 3 -->
      <img src="../img/company-name.png" alt="company-name-logo"/>
      <!-- Logo 4 -->
      <img src="../img/tesco.png" alt="tesco-logo"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <div>
      <!-- Logo 1 -->
      <img src="../img/dove.png" alt="dove-logo"/>
      <!-- Logo 2 -->
      <img src="../img/company-name.png" alt="company-name-logo"/>
      <!-- Logo 3 -->
      <img src="../img/tesco.png" alt="tesco-logo"/>
      <!-- Logo 4 -->
      <img src="../img/company-name.png" alt="company-name-logo"/>
    </div>

  </section>

  <footer>
        <div class="footer-stuff">
            <div class="social">
                <strong>Find Us On</strong>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" class="fa fa-twitter"><!-- Twitter --></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="fa fa-instagram"><!-- Facebook --></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest"><!-- Pinterest --></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="fa fa-youtube"><!-- Instagram --></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- <div class="columns three">
              <strong>OTHER SHOPS</strong>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Red Robin</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Emerald Eagle</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Crimson Crane</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Auburn Abbot</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> -->

            <div class="sign-up">
                <p>
                    <strong>Sign Up for the newsletter</strong>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          <br/>
          consectetur adipisicing elit.
                </p>

                <form action="">
                    <div>
                        <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../scripts/functions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* height: 2000px; */
  /* background: red; */
  color: #333;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-size: cover;
}



/*************************************************
HERO
**************************************************/

.hero {
  background: pink url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: 100% 4%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 100vh;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.hero .overlay {
  /* height: 900px; */
}

/* Vertical Nav */
.nav {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  /* z-index: 1000; */
}

.nav li {
  font-size: .7em;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.startLogo {
  position: fixed;
}

.altLogo {
  position: absolute;
}

.white li a {
  color: white;
}

.black li a {
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

/* down arrow */
.hero svg {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  width: 5vw;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5vw);
  bottom: 100px;
  fill: black;
}


/* Triangle */
#triangle-left {
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 0;
  border-top: 500px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50vw solid white;
  border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;
  /* margin-top: calc(100vh - 590.5px); */
  top: calc(100vh - 500px);
  /* left: 0; */
  /* z-index: 1; */
}

#triangle-left nav {
  /* position: fixed;
  left: -50vw;
  top: -500px;
  z-index:1000; */
}

/* #triangle-left nav li {
  font-size: .7em;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#triangle-left nav li a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
} */



/* Triangle Right */
#triangle-right {
  position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50vw solid white;
    border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;
  top: calc(100vh - 500px);
  right: 0;
}



/* Content */
.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 100px 5% 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.content p {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}



/**********************************************
MAIN
***********************************************/

/* Skewed Box */
.skewedBox {
  background: #add8e6;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 0;
  transform: skew(0deg, 5deg);
  /* z-index: -1000; */
  margin-top: -80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* height: 600px; */
}

.skewedBox-container {
  transform: skew(0deg, -5deg);
  padding: 100px 5%;
}

.skewedBox-container h1,
.skewedBox-container p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

/* Sections */
/* Section1 */
#section1 {
  background: white;
  padding: 200px 5%;
  position: relative;
  transform: skew(0deg, 5deg);
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  margin-bottom: -300px;
}
#section1 p {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transform: skew(0deg, -5deg);
}



/* Section2 */
#section2 {
  background: white;
  padding: 100px 10% 150px;
  margin-bottom: 297px;
}

#section2 h2 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#section2 div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#section2 div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#section2 img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}



/* Floating Boxes */
.floating-boxes {
  background: pink url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: -1000; */
}

.floating-boxes .overlay {
  height: 2000px;
}



/* Primary */
#primary {
  background: pink;
  height: 500px;
  width: 415px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 6%;

  /* transform: translate(0, 20%); */
}

#primary .content {
  background: white;
  height: 505px;
  width: 415px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  left: -5%;
}



/* Secondary */
#secondary {
  background: lightyellow;
  height: 465px;
  width: 415px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  bottom: 37%;
}
#secondary .content {
  background: white;
  height: 465px;
  width: 415px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  left: -5%;
}



/* Tertiary */
#tertiary {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 465px;
  width: 415px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
#tertiary .content {
  background: white;
  height: 465px;
  width: 415px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  left: -5%;
}



/**********************************************
FOOTER
***********************************************/

/* Universal */
footer {
    background: #add8e6;
    color: white;
    padding: 70px 5%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.footer-stuff {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer-stuff strong {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

footer a {
    color: white;
}

.social,
.sign-up {
  margin: auto ;
}



/* Social */
.social ul {
  display: flex;
}

.social ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}



/* Sign-Up */
.sign-up  {
  /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
}
.sign-up p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}



/* Email Input */
.sign-up input[type="email"] {
  padding: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
.sign-up input[type="email"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: lightblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.sign-up input[type="email"]::placeholder {
  color: lightblue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Submit Input */
input[type="submit"] {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: white;
  color: lightblue;
}

/* fa fa */
.social [class*="fa fa-"] {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin: auto 3px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function logoSwitch () {
      $('.altLogo').each(function() {
        $(this).css('top',
          $('.startLogo').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.row').offset().top
        );
      });
    };

    $(document).scroll(function() {logoSwitch();});

    logoSwitch();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LukeBennettUK/dxm21vo1/

https://github.com/LukeBennettUK/Testing-Update-

If you need any more information please let me know and I will be happy to edit the post and give it to you.

Thanks so much,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `z-index` order. The easiest way with the least amount of code is defining containers in the negative.

```
 .hero nav.nav.startLogo {
    z-index: 1;
    }
 .hero {
    z-index: -2;
    }
 footer{
    z-index:-3;
    }
```

Since your footer already had a value of `z-index:-1;` we had to re-define it as `z-index:-3;`

To turn the text in that section black just update your html from this

```
<nav class="nav black startLogo">
```

to this

```
<nav class="nav white startLogo">
```

or you could force it with css by adding this code if you are unable to alter the html.

```
.hero nav ul li a {
    color: black;
}
```

## [UPDATED JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gr468eut/1/)

<sup>(I put the new CSS at the bottom of the stylesheet in the js fiddle link above.)</sup>

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for helping out with that. I may have to go with the black colour at the top if I cannot get it to stay white. I don't think I explained myself well enough sorry. I have updated the question, but what I want to happen is for the nav to begin white in color, and then as it does with other divs, change to black as it scrolls over it. Thank you so much for the help so far, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You mean everything is fine but IN THE PINK TRIANGLE you want the text to be white?

Comment: Yes, text white in the pink triangle. But I wanted it to change to black when it was scrolled over the left white triangle div named #triangle-left. Is it due to it all being within the .hero container? Do I need to remove #triangle-left from the .hero container perhaps?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. You just cant do it with the border blocking the text. Its impossible using that method. I would consider making an SVG for the triangle that way you can properly layer it to cover the respective navigation without the border issue.

Comment: Ah, I see, that is a good idea. I will give that a go, and report my findings once I have completed it. Thank you for your help thus far. I am fairly new to web development, so it is great just to have someone else's opinion. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: No problem. Its a cool effect you're going for. SVG's are great because they can be any shape and they can also be containers.

If you need to put html inside the svg (which i think you will need to put the nav html inside one) just use the foreignObject tags to wrap your html inside the svg tag. 

https://web.archive.org/web/20120418122612/http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have created two SVG's but Something weird is happening with the navigation, it seems to be hiding behind something. https://jsfiddle.net/LukeBennettUK/spg7fmfe/